# which ffmpeg api is for the cmd option "-q:v 1" by saving jpg from video

Tags: ffmpeg

as the theme,  how can I set quality scale with ffmpeg-api. I want to extract frame from video and save it as .jpg. Maybe I should set some av_dictionory?

Thanks for reading and hope you can leave some answer.

Answer (score 0):

`-q` in ffmpeg CLI is for setting a `qscale` (see: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html).
Looking inside ffmpeg CLI code `qscale` parameter is mapped to `AVCodecContext.global_quality` like this: https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n4.3.2/fftools/ffmpeg_opt.c#L1550